# How to get_the_date() of post inside an action hook function?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Trying to get **current post date**  inside an **action hook** function for **custom post type**. How to get all the details of the current post inside there. Or at least the post date? I have tried many things. Sorry if it's easy, I am a beginner in Wordpress.

```
add_action('init', 'Theme2035_lyric_register');  

function Theme2035_lyric_register() {   
    echo get_the_date(); 

    ---other code below---

}
```

Comment: I am trying here to get the post date and add it after the permalink with rewrite link option.

Comment: The global $post object is not available within the init hook as it has not been populated yet.  You'd need to use the "wp" hook to get access to the post_date field.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're looking for [`the_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/the_post) action hook:

```
function my_the_post_action( $post_object ) {
    $post_date = $post_object->post_date;
    // do something with $post_date
}
add_action( 'the_post', 'my_the_post_action' );
```

If you want to get more attribute of `$post_object`, you may want to take a look at [WP_Post class reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post).